# Store output of for loop into single variable

Tags: python

I have a for loop that retrieves bigram data of a page of text from an SQLite3 database.

```
def bigram_db():
cursr.execute("SELECT * FROM trainedGrammar")
data = cursr.fetchall()
for data in data:
    element = data
    txt = element[0] #fetch first element of list
    txt += txt
return txt
```

I tried using txt += txt but this only gives me a single paragraph worth bigram data when I tried to print cache outside the function bigram_db(). So how do I store all of the bigram data that is going to be output by the for loop, which can be **accessed outside of the for loop** and then when I print it, I want the entire bigram data of the database to be available.

Comment: What [data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) do you want?

Comment: @CL.,but the problem is it only gives me one paragraph of data, there is actually 4. But when I type "print txt" within the for loop, it gives me all 4 paragraphs I want to do the same but outside the for loop

Comment: First of all, use better naming (you are using data twice). better do `for row in data:` and also remove the redundant assignment `element = data`

Comment: @dnaranjo Thanks for the advice! yah, it's redundant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to execute `fetchall()`, you can iterate directly on the cursor. And you cannot use the same variable `txt` for two purposes; in the loop, the line `txt = element[0]` overwrites its old value.

Your function should look like this:

```
def bigram_db():
    cursr.execute("SELECT * FROM trainedGrammar")
    txt = ""
    for row in cursr:
        txt += row[0]
    return txt
```

Or without a for loop:

```
def bigram_db():
    cursr.execute("SELECT * FROM trainedGrammar")
    return "".join([row[0] for row in cursr])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this.